# How to update a mysql database via SMS text messaging

Tags: php

I want to add an additional functionality to a CMS I am making that will allow users to add content to a site via text message. The user should be able to add text by send the message to a number which when received will update the database accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form is too broad. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: what country are you in? you're probably gonna have too find a local service which can receive text messages on a preset number, which will then be forwarded to some endpoint of your choice. i know of some good providers in sweden, but those providers are only interesting for you if you're in sweden :)

Comment: @arpan welcome to SO, you should find a gateway provider take a look at these http://www.google.com/search?aq=1&oq=two+way+sms&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=two+way+sms+gateway

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098288/how-to-update-a-mysql-database-via-sms-text-messaging

Comment: @rickchristie: Possible plagiarism, even! Blimey.

Answer (score 0):

*You have some options - but a SMS gateway is the ideal solution.*

**Alternatively,**

What you will do outside of a number - is to email from the phone. Using PHP - you can interpret the email to look for a keyword in the body or subject line and run a script accordingly.

All SMS capable phones can SEND email from text messages. Instead of entering number - you enter an email address.

It is a very lo-fi version of the implementation - but this method worked perfectly for me and for those not interested in investing in an SMS gateway.